# Using browser-sync with vue js and framework7

Tags: vue.js, webpack, browser-sync, html-framework-7

I have created a PWA using vue js 2.0 and framework7 and also use Webpack for bundling. I want to use browser-sync to share my project.

I used this config in my webpack.confg file :

```
  new BrowserSyncPlugin({
    // browse to http://localhost:3000/ during development,
    // ./public directory is being served
    host: 'localhost,
    port: 3000,
    server: { baseDir: ['src'] }
  }),
```

In `src/` I have my basic files like `index.html`, `app.vue`, `app.js`.
After using npm run dev command I see this result :

```
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.118::3000
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 ----------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: src
```

After this, `localhost:3000` open in my browser and say `browsersync: connected` but it have showed me a blank page. 
Also after I enter website path (`http://localhost:3000/en/#!/login`) in browser, it showed me `Cannot Get /en` Error. What is the problem?

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your compiled files in `src`?

Comment: No, my compiled files are in another path. after adding that path I can see a basic view of my app but again after adding complete website path I give cannot open /en again

Comment: Are you using `vue-router`?

Comment: No, I'm using framework7 router. it's a part of framework7vue

Comment: What are you using to serve the application i.e. what command are you running?

Comment: with "npm run dev" and dev is "webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.dev.js --host 0.0.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, looks like you are also using `webpack-dev-server`. In that case you can proxy to it:

```
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  // ...

  devServer: {
    port: 3100
  }

  // ...

  plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin(
      // BrowserSync options
      {
        // browse to http://localhost:3000/ during development
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        // proxy the Webpack Dev Server endpoint
        // (which should be serving on http://localhost:3100/)
        // through BrowserSync
        proxy: 'http://localhost:3100/'
      },
      // plugin options
      {
        // prevent BrowserSync from reloading the page
        // and let Webpack Dev Server take care of this
        reload: false
      }
    )
  ]
}
```